# How do I add path exception in Redirect and Fast 404 modules?

Tags: redirection

I have a module which has dynamic paths (e.g. /mymodule/one/file1/a.png, /mymodule/one/two/three, /mymodule/one/two/three/four/b.js), where the number of path parameters are resolved by a class implementing the `InboundPathprocessor` interface. mymodule is present in all the paths.

I want the *Redirect* and the *Fast 404* module to ignore paths with "mymodule" in it.

Answer (score -1):

Using an OutBoundPathProcessor and reversing the path logic in it worked for me